# why I am facing error in State while create room in DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

```json
{
  "name": "Testing000000001",
  "roleId": "2007958",
  "transactionSideId": "listbuy",
  "fieldData": {
    "data" : {
     "address1": "123 EZ Street",
     "address2": "unit 10",
     "city": "Galaxian",
     "state": "US-HI",
     "postalCode": "11112",
     "companyRoomStatus": "5",
     "comments": " laborum.",
     "hubspotId":"121212"
      }
   }
}
```

This code is running fine but when ever I changed the value of State from US-HI to another value, so it show error while creating a room.

Comment: What value did you try? "US-NY" worked for me, you can prebaby do all 50 states in US

Answer (score 0):

The [Rooms:CreateRoom](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/rooms-api/reference/rooms/rooms/createroom/) endpoint documentation says this:

[image]

If you check the [State:GetStates](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/rooms-api/reference/globalresources/states/getstates/) documentation you will see the list of states, but to get their codes you have to make this API call. If you want you can make it once and hardcode the results, changes to the list of states are rare.